# Looping through XML with namespace PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

I have a xml curl response like this:

```
<ns2:categorys xmlns:ns2="http://skt.tmall.business.openapi.spring.service.client.domain">
    <ns2:category>
        <depth>1</depth>
        <dispengnm>Women Clothing</dispengnm>
        <dispnm>Pakaian Wanita</dispnm>
        <dispno>1</dispno>
        <parentdispno>0</parentdispno>
    </ns2:category>
    <ns2:category>
        <depth>2</depth>
        <dispengnm>Dresses &amp; Suits</dispengnm>
        <dispnm>Gaun &amp; Terusan</dispnm>
        <dispno>2</dispno>
        <parentdispno>1</parentdispno>
    </ns2:category>
</ns2:categorys>
```

i tried to get the data inside the `<ns2:category>` using this code:

```
$return = curl_exec($ch);

$return= simplexml_load_string($return);
$categories = $return->children('ns2', true);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump(count($categories)); 
foreach ($categories as $category) {
  print_r($category->depth);
}
```

but all i got is :

```
int(2)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `getNamespaces` to `true` before looping the data, and inside the loop you need to call the children function so it will get the data and wrapped it inside an object variable

```
$return = simplexml_load_string($return);
$ns = $return->getNamespaces(true);

foreach ($return->children($ns['ns2'])->category as $key) {
  $data = $key->children();
  echo  $data->depth;
}
```